# Angular - lazy loading 2 modules and need to share same service

Tags: angular

**Shared Module:**

```
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        MyService
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**Lazy Loaded Module #1:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class LazyModule1 { }
```

**Lazy Loaded Module #2:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class LazyModule2 { }
```

---

I need one instance, but doing it this way creates 2 new singleton services.
Is it possible to do this without importing SharedModule.forRoot() in the AppModule? Any alternatives? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use same service in 2 different modules. Then register your service in root module where you define you both lazy loaded routes. In this case you will have single instance for multiple modules and components.